# How to set the overscroll from ThemeData

Tags: flutter

I have tried to change accentColor, colorScheme, primaryColor, secondaryColor, but none could change the overscroll color it still blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a MaterialApp, the edge glow color is the overall theme's `ColorScheme.secondary` color.

[GlowingOverscrollIndicator Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlowingOverscrollIndicator-class.html)

[ThemeData Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Update `theme` in `MaterialApp` in main.dart like this:

```
theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          buttonColor: Colors.purple,
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
        )
    ),
```